# C++ Multi Switch and Break?

Tags: c++

lets say I have a Code like this

```
    switch (something)
    {
      case 0:
           switch (anotherthing)
           {
             case 0:
                break;
             case 1:
                break;
             default:
                break;
           }

    case 1:
    case 4:
      break;
    case 2:
    case 3:
      break;
    default:
      break;
}
```

Now if I use Case 0 and go to switch (anotherthing), and use break there what will be happen? finish switch (anotherthing)? or Finish switch (something) too?

Is this same in other languages too?

Comment: You could test this in under 2 minutes...

Comment: `break`quits from **current** loop/switch.

Comment: Compiling and running this code will give a much more reliable answer than we can. And in much less time. Just add some cout statements.

Comment: You'll learn a lot more if you actually try things to figure it out than you will by depending on other people to tell you. It's about 30seconds effort to actually compile and run your code to see what happens; add another two minutes to that to insert a couple of `printf` or `cout` statements to see what's happening (or better yet, another minute to learn how to step through in a debugger). Put some effort into learning; it'll pay off very quickly when you're stuck somewhere without an internet connection and need to get something done, and it feels a lot better to know you did it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `break` statement only breaks the closest switch/loop that it is called in.

In your example, the `break` statements of the inner `switch` would only break out of the inner `switch`, execution would return to `case 0` of the other `switch`.  And then, since that `case 0` does not have a `break` of its own, execution would fall through to `case 1`, which also does not have a `break`, so execution would fall through to `case 4`, which does have a `break` to end the outer `switch`.

This is certainly true in C and C++, anyway.  Not necessarily in other languages.  For example, Delphi does not fall-through between case blocks.  `Break` can be used to end a `case` block early, but it is optional, the block is finished when the end of its scope is reached.

Answer (score 1):

The break will only break out of the innermost switch.

The example you provided would be easy to test this behavior with the addition of some `print` statements or line breaks.

Please see [this documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/break) on the behavior of C++ breaks.